# Import Data from IBM Connection Docs Excel URL in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, ibm-connections

My company recently transitioned to IBM Connections and has closed down a few features like Box.com.

IBM Connections can also store files, but when uploading them, I cannot connect Tableau to them directly as the file path is a URL and Tableau cannot get files from URLs.

I've tried to load it in Power Query and then load it in Tableau but then I need to find a way to refresh the file while the original Excel file gets edited.

Any suggestions how can I get a live connection from IBM Connections Docs > Tableau Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe a live connection is possible. However, it looks like IBM provides a [robust api](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/lcwiki.nsf/xpAPIViewer.xsp?lookupName=IBM%20Connections%205.5%20API%20Documentation#action=openDocument&content=catcontent&ct=api).  Depending on your requirements, you could script something that writes out a json file. Then use tableau to refresh the json as an extract on a schedule. Another possibility is the Web Data Connector.